# How to use Javascript to open a certain amount of tabs in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, loops

In this code, JavaScript is used to open a youtube channel link from the downloaded "subscription_manager.xml" file in a new Google Chrome tab. The if statement with "index === 1" is a safeguard (because I have over 200 subscriptions) so that it only opens one tab. I am trying to get it to open at least 10 tabs but every time I adjust the statement it gets ignored no matter what amount I enter, so instead it tries to open all the links and uses all the RAM and crashes my PC. I have tried the for, while, and do-while loops, all result in failure. Can someone teach/show me what to do or what it is I'm not understanding?

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    childProcess = require('child_process'),
    xml2js = require('xml2js');

var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/subscription_manager.xml', function (err, data) {
    parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
        var nodes = result.opml.body[0].outline[0].outline;

        nodes.forEach(function (node, index) {
            var url = node['$'].xmlUrl;
            url = url.substring(url.indexOf('=') + 1, url.length);
            var channel = 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/' + url;

            if (index === 1) { 
                childProcess.exec('start chrome ' + channel);

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: you should detail the code of the loops you tried

Comment: Example of one I used:  for (index = 1; index<=10; index++) very simple

Comment: What happens if you use this loop and replace childProcess.exec('start chrome ' + channel); with console.log(index,channel) ?

Comment: The terminal logged 10 copies of the all the links. So 2200 lines of url's, then I changed "index<=10" to "index<=1" and it logged one of each link. I only need it to open a portion of the file and loops don't seem to work right in this situation so I think I shouldn't use any.

Comment: You should update the code to show where your  loop really is...